# D3's data update not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

After calling my rects.enter().append(), my rects.attr() is not setting values for the newly appended values.

```
let rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)

//On update Only
rects.attr('fill', 'black')

//On enter ...
rects.enter()
    .append('rect')
    .style('fill', 'maroon')

//On update AND enter
rects
    .attr('x', (d, i)=>i*(barWidth+padding))
    .attr('y', d=>height - bar_height(d.value))
    .attr('width', barWidth)
    .attr('height', d=> bar_height(d['value']))
```

Basically, my understanding is in the comments. If I haven't called enter(), it will only apply changes to previous values in data. This simply should have the bar be a different color. Then I enter() and change the color to the new ones added, and finally, I expect that now that all are inside rects so to speak, it should update the attributes of all of them.

The problem is that the final attributes are only being set to those values that weren't appended, so first pass nothing is being drawn, then the second pass it's being drawn as an update.

I tried basing my changes on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38065997/d3-js-attribute-setting-not-working-after-binding-data-and-entering-elements), and that's where I'm at.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47032222/7106086), v3 had a slightly different update pattern, v4+ changed this and introduced the merge method to account for that change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the rest of your code to ensure that this works. You should use [.merge()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge). For v3 the method is different, this is for v4+.

```
let rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)

//On update Only
rects.attr('fill', 'black')

//On enter ...
rects.enter()
    .append('rect')
    .style('fill', 'maroon')
    .merge(rects)
    .attr('x', (d, i)=>i*(barWidth+padding))
    .attr('y', d=>height - bar_height(d.value))
    .attr('width', barWidth)
    .attr('height', d=> bar_height(d['value']))
```

This will merge the newly added `rects` into the selection of the existing rects and will update all of them with everything that comes after the `merge` statement.

Comment: This worked, why did the other way not work? Was it just an older version of d3?

Comment: @DavidWestwood yes between v3 and v4 they changed how this works. I'll edit to add version to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem and answered my question!